# How to restrict SVN repository user account to one directory?

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, repository, privileges

I have a SVN repository with a user in passwd:

```
[users]
Mark = 8d9"'8V2;
```

Now i would like to restrict this user privilages (permissions) only to commit and update this directories:

```
/CurrentProject/Printer
/CurrentProject/Scanner
/CurrentProject/Documentation
```

How to acomplish this?

Comment: More of a serverfault question, isn't it?

Comment: @Lucas SVN is more programmers issue not a server administrator issue, actually SVN and subversion tags here have thousands of questions.

Comment: I just want to say that serverfault is pretty much useless for getting any svn questions answered

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out [Path-Based Authorization](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.serverconfig.pathbasedauthz.html) in the SVN Book.

In svnserve.conf, specify a authz-db file. And in that file say something like the following.

```
[/]
Tomas = rw

[/CurrentProject]
Mark = rw
```